# problem with jquery sortable and guids

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I have

```
<ul id="test-list" class="ui-sortable" >
   <li id="876e45a4-6a27-4f7b-95ca-9e2500f11801">text1</li>
   <li id="4df36ffb-561a-4eaa-9b1c-9e2500f16d6b">text2</li>
   <li id="cc4a57d5-1567-403c-888f-9e2500f1c171">text3</li>
</ul>
```

but `$('#test-list').sortable('serialize');` does a string like this: 
`876e45a4-6a27-4f7b-95ca[]=9e2500f11801&79fbfdf7-e9b1-4e96-8e42[]=9e2400d2abb7&4df36ffb-561a-4eaa-9b1c[]`

removing last 12 chars of id

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5):

**Two things:**

#### `Sortable.serialize`'s IDs

Are you sure `Sortable`'s `serialize` does what you're expecting it to do? According to [the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize), it expects the ID of each sortable element to be in the form `setname_number`. The IDs are expected to have an underscore in them, but will fall back to using an `=` or `-`; from [the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize):

> It works by default by looking at the id of each item in the format 'setname_number', and it spits out a hash like "setname[]=number&setname[]=number".
>   
> ...They must be in the form: "set_number" For example, a 3 element list with id attributes `foo_1`, `foo_5`, `foo_2` will serialize to `foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2`. **You can use an underscore, equal sign or hyphen to separate the set and number.** For example `foo=1` or `foo-1` or `foo_1` all serialize to `foo[]=1`.

(My emphasis.) So not having seen an underscore (`_`), apparently it's falling back to using the last hyphen (`-`) it sees.

#### `id` format for use with CSS

Separately, `id` values for use with CSS **cannot** begin with a digit; from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier):

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A1 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, or a hyphen followed by a digit.

(These restrictions are not true for `id` in HTML, which just can't contain spaces and has to have at least one character if given, but CSS is more restrictive.)

Since you're using CSS selectors with jQuery, it would probably be best to ensure that the `id` attributes are valid CSS. (Perhaps you could preprocess them to be "G" followed by the GUID with the dashes converted to `x`, that sort of thing, so the IDs are `G876e45a4x6a27x4f7bx95cax9e2500f11801` and the like.) Then you'll want to give them an underscore and suffix as per the above.

Comment: Good point, though I quickly did a test with letters after every hyphen on his issue and it is still present.

Comment: @Orbling: I was just editing as you commented there, I think the problem is at much (or more) to do with the new first part of my answer as the second. :-)

Comment: @TJ By the time I had discovered what was what, you had altered your answer to say what I was saying.  Though you, being eminently sensible went to the docs, whereas I looked at the code.  Only plus side for me is I know where the code needs to be modified if the hyphens are needed. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

For [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html) like `876e45a4-6a27-4f7b-95ca-9e2500f11801` you can add parameter.

```
$(this).sortable('serialize', {expression:(/(.+)[_](.+)/)})
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. The way I solved it was by changing the view's code to replace the dash character with the empty string:

```html
<div id="divItems">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div id="@string.Format("item_{0}", item.Id.ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty))">
        @item.Title
    </div>
}
</div>
```

Note: I used div instead of ul/li for my situation.

My javascript looks like this:

```js
$("div#divItems").sortable({
    cursor: "move",
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var container = $(this);
        var sequence = container.sortable("serialize", { key: "Sequence" });
        $.post("@Url.Action("EditSequence")", sequence, function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                container.fadeTo("normal", 0, function () {
                    container.fadeTo("normal", 1);
                });
            } else {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Note: I changed the key to 'Sequence' and the fadeTo() combo is used for visual feedback to the user that the sequence saved successfully.

My Controller Action method looks like this:

```c#
// POST: /Showcase/EditSequence?Sequence=<Guid List>
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditSequence(List<Guid> Sequence)
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Sequence.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = repos.GetSingle(Sequence[i]);
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.Seq = (i + 1);
            }
        }

        repos.Save();

        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Sequence has been saved!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
}
```

The model binder takes care of converting the Guid strings without the dashes into a List<Guid> bound to the Sequence parameter.

Comment: You can do item.Id.ToString("N") in your view, as an alternative to the .Remove() method.

Answer (score 1):

Changing it to `$('#test-list').sortable('serialize').replace(/=\[\]/g, '-')` works around the weird issue, but it must be some oddity in the jQuery UI code with the long IDs.  I will look further.

**Update**

Right the offending code in `jquery.ui.sortable.js` in the `serialize()` routine is:

```
$(items).each(function() {
    var res = ($(o.item || this).attr(o.attribute || 'id') || '').match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/));
    if(res) str.push((o.key || res[1]+'[]')+'='+(o.key && o.expression ? res[1] : res[2]));
});
```

This is deliberately functionality, it is detecting ids containing a dash (-), equals or underscore, and treating them as array values, left/right dividing array and key values.  Perhaps use a bar `|` instead, or amend `serialize()` for your usage.